# javascript if statement boolean comparison not working

Tags: javascript

```js
var keydownTriggered = false;
console.log(keydownTriggered);
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Keydown Start Offset", window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset);
    console.log("Keydown End Offset", window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset);
    keydownTriggered = true;
    console.log(keydownTriggered);
  }, 0);
})
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  keydownTriggered = false;
  console.log(keydownTriggered);
})

if (!keydownTriggered) {
  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log("Click: Keydown Start Offset", window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset);
    console.log("Click: Keydown End Offset", window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset);
    keydownTriggered = false;
    console.log(keydownTriggered);
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="form" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

This code shouldn't trigger the `'click'` event when the `'keydown'` event is triggered. For example, when I'm long pressing `'A'` it means that 'keydown' is triggered so when I click anywhere in the `contenteditable` element, the `console.log` inside the `if` statement should not be triggered.
However, I get this result.

```
test.html:10 Keydown Start Offset 8
test.html:11 Keydown End Offset 8
test.html:13 true
test.html:23 Click: Keydown Start Offset 8
test.html:24 Click: Keydown End Offset 8
test.html:26 false
test.html:10 Keydown Start Offset 9
test.html:11 Keydown End Offset 9
```

The value of `keydownTriggered` is `true` is seen in line 13 but the if statement is still triggered.

I tried changing the `if` statement to `(keydownTriggered == true)`, `(keydownTriggered === true)` and tried changing all boolean value to numbers (`true` to `1` and `false` to `0`) but got nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `if statement` in the `click event inside`, otherwise when you click, `the click event callback` will always be run

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!keydownTriggered){
        console.log("Click: Keydown Start Offset", window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset);
        console.log("Click: Keydown End Offset", window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset);
        keydownTriggered = false;
        console.log(keydownTriggered);
    }
})
```